# To change Browser's settings with c# code

Tags: c#, firefox, browser

I m trying to do following with c# code.

1) Open Firefox Browser --->Tools--->Options--->In General Tab--->Downloads--->Always ask me where to save file.

I want to do this whole process in my application with c# code. I want that when download window opens , the radio button in "Always ask me where to save file" option gets checked automatically.
  I got the code from this site ..but that works only when firefox in not running. I m using the code in application and running that application in Firefox browser.
I have tried from various links , but all is in vain. Any help will be greatly rewarded. Thanxxx in advance..!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If by "and running that application in Firefox browser" you mean you've written an ASP.NET web app, I highly doubt you're going to be able to do this. It would probably be considered a security flaw in Firefox if it allowed a web page to change this setting.

Comment: Agreed, it's plausible to do it with a C# desktop application (_possibly_ an `xbap` application) through some tom-foolery, but any other platform would likely need to leverage an exploit (I doubt such an exploit exists)

Answer (score 2):

You could try modifying the code [here](http://sturla.simnet.is/post/2008/09/22/Enable-proxy-in-IE.aspx). But that code will only run on your machine or in your own program that you can distribute. Like said in the other answer you will not be able to run this from the browser. This sounds like something that was done with ActiveX but that´s [no longer supported](http://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/ActiveX) by Firefox.